# Mobile Services + Xamarin - Sync - Query params in lower camel case rather than upper

Tags: xamarin, azure-mobile-services

So I have an Azure mobile services project created in `c#` coupled with an `xamarin android mobile` app, which do not want to sync with each other. The problem appears to be on the odata query it generates.

I expected this to be the solution

```
this.mobileService = new MobileServiceClient(Helpers.Keys.AzureServiceUrl)
{
    SerializerSettings = new MobileServiceJsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        CamelCasePropertyNames = true //expected this to solve my problems
    }
};
```

When it comes to syncing it creates a url (notice the lower case camel at updatedAt):

**http://localhost:64890/tables/CupOfCoffee?$filter=(updatedAt ge datetimeoffset'1970-01-01T00%3A00%3A00.0000000%2B00%3A00')&$orderby=updatedAt&$skip=0&$top=50&__includeDeleted=true**

which the service rejects with

```js
{
  "message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'updatedAt' on type 'CoffeeAppWebServices.DataObjects.CupOfCoffee'.",
  "exceptionMessage": "Could not find a property named 'updatedAt' on type 'CoffeeAppWebServices.DataObjects.CupOfCoffee'.",
  "exceptionType": "Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException",
  "stackTrace": "   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.EndPathBinder.GeneratePropertyAccessQueryForOpenType(EndPathToken endPathToken, SingleValueNode parentNode)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.EndPathBinder.BindEndPath(EndPathToken endPathToken, BindingState state)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.MetadataBinder.BindEndPath(EndPathToken endPathToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.MetadataBinder.Bind(QueryToken token)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.OrderByBinder.ProcessSingleOrderBy(BindingState state, OrderByClause thenBy, OrderByToken orderByToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.OrderByBinder.BindOrderBy(BindingState state, IEnumerable`1 orderByTokens)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.ODataUriParser.ParseOrderByImplementation(String orderBy, IEdmType elementType, IEdmEntitySet entitySet)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.ODataUriParser.ParseOrderBy(String orderBy, IEdmType elementType, IEdmEntitySet entitySet)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.ODataUriParser.ParseOrderBy(String orderBy, IEdmModel model, IEdmType elementType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.OrderByQueryOption.get_OrderByClause()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Validators.OrderByQueryValidator.Validate(OrderByQueryOption orderByOption, ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.OrderByQueryOption.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Validators.ODataQueryValidator.Validate(ODataQueryOptions options, ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ValidateQuery(HttpRequestMessage request, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object response, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)"
}
```

So that fails... 
Quite simply changing the query params from 'updatedAt' to 'UpdatedAt' (upper camel case or pascal case) it will make the above query work. How can I get the xamarin app to generate that way or have the mobile servies accept the lower camel case variation, which im more use to webapi just accepting either format?

As a relevent note: the coffee cup entity on the mobile services implements
`EntityData`

But i cant seem to find anything on the tutorials that mention switching lower camel case to upper.

Any ideas? Or need more information... ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll add another query into the mix ... I have two azure mobile services. 
one uses: "WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.*" and the other: "Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.*" this project is becoming more and more confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing and matching Azure Mobile Apps with Azure Mobile Services.  They are not compatible.

Your best idea at this point is to switch your Mobile Service over to App Service.  You can find information on the upgrade here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-net-upgrading-from-mobile-services/

Comment: I was wondering how I ended up with two projects started a week apart being so different. I gave up on the project starting with Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server as it was complaining about a similar thing with the sync. I'll see if it repeats itself with the coffee version after its updated.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. 
That fixed the request for Postman and hopefully the sync from xamarin will work this time.